# How to compute the frequency of words in a file in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, mean

I am reading words in each file and storing them in a list.

I was able to count how many times each word occurs in that file.

Here's my code for that.

```
for name in files:
    if name.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(name, "r") as word_list:
             words = word_list.read().split()

        counts = Counter(words)

        labels, values = zip(*counts.items())

        labels = np.array(labels)
        values = np.array(values)
```

This code and further code of mine combined, produces a Histogram of the number

of this a word occurs. This is where I am counting the words.

I need to divide each word occurrence number and the total number of words in a file to get discrete distribution.

How can I achieve that goal ?

---

(original title: *Python. How to get a average of words in a file?*)

Comment: Are you looking for the median or the mean?

Comment: Its the count of each word divided by the total number of words in the file. That should be done for each element. Their frequency divided by the total words

Comment: What do you mean by "average of words"?

Comment: Yes. My code only produces the total number of each word by itself. I need to divide each of the number of each element by the total

Comment: Where are you stuck in writing that code?  You have the length and sum methods to give you the needed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frequency is, as you are suggesting yourself, simply given by the following:

```
total = np.sum(values)
freqs = values / total
```

(could be combined, I wrote it like this to make it more clear)

I am not sure how this is related to the "average of words", whatever that means.

Comment: Thanks ! appreciated!

Comment: @TwinDream if it helps you, please accept this answer